# Accessor Not Working Even Though Column Exists?

Tags: laravel

I have a column in the "products" table called "walkover_only". I can access this attribute easily anywhere with $product->walkover_only, but I can't change it with an accessor?

```
public function getWalkoverOnlyAttribute($value)
{
    if (strpos($this->name, 'Test') !== false) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

I've tried even just `return 0` with no if statement, and everything still just returns its normal value. It doesn't need $appends because I can access the value everywhere just fine, it's a real column. I just can't affect what it returns in any way.

Comment: Er actually, if you have a column called `walkover_only`, I think you need to name your attribute differently, like `getModifiedWalkoverOnlyAttribute()`, and `$product->modified_walkover_only` can return either `return 0;` (based on your check) or `return $this->walkover_only;`

Comment: @TimLewis but I can do `getNameAttribute($value)` and modify my `name` column without having to rename it something else, and a few other ones I've done before where I only modify the column value based on certain conditions. I'm thinking maybe Laravel thinks "walkover" isn't a word? lol

Comment: Hmm, I thought it had to be different, since `getNameAttribute()`, returning `$this->name` would be an infinite loop. That being said, I've never used `getNameAttribute($value)`, so it makes sense that returning `$value` instead of `$this->name` would avoid that issue. As for `walkover` not being a word, I don't think that matters? But maybe it does. Interesting issue none-the-less.